# AutoFac Delegate Factories and the Lifetime Scope

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm using delegate Factories in my application. Thats because the components I create with AutoFac use Service classes that need some Parameter.

The next Thing I wanted to do is caring that these services are cleaned up correctly and resources are released using AutoFacs lifetime scope mechanism. The Problem however is that when I create the components using the delegate factories they seem not to be put into the lifetime scope and Dispose is not called after disposing the lifetime scope.

I want to avoid the generic Owned<> because I dont want to bind my application to a specific IOC.

In http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/ it is explained that the created components by a delegate factory are put into the same lifetime scope as the delegate factory.

I wrote a small Programm to demonstrate this. In this Program I would expect that the Dispose function is called. Unfortunatley this doesnt happen. Do I miss here sth? Anything wrong with the code below? How can I assure that components produced by the delegate factory are put into the life time scope of the delegate factory?

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;
using System;

namespace FactoryTest
{
class Component : IDisposable
{
    public Component(int i) { }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register<Func<int, Component>>(c => (x) =>
        {
            // code that is important and that should run
            // inside the delegate factory.
            return new Component(x);
            });

        IContainer root = builder.Build();

        using (ILifetimeScope lf = root.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            Func<int, Component> compDelegatefac = lf.Resolve<Func<int, Component>>();
            Component cmp = compDelegatefac(2);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you initialize your `Component` with runtime data. Prevent doing this since it is [bad practice](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
If you don't want to use Auto Generated Factories you can follow [Delegate Factories](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html)

```
namespace FactoryTest
{
    class Component : IDisposable
    {
        public delegate Component Factory(int i);
        public Component(int i) { Console.WriteLine(i); }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Component disposed");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<Component>().AsSelf();

            IContainer root = builder.Build();

            using (ILifetimeScope lf = root.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var compDelegatefac = lf.Resolve<Component.Factory>();
                Component cmp = compDelegatefac(2);
            }
            GC.Collect();

            Console.Read();
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hey Erkan thx for that. Unfortunatley I cannot use autogenerated factories. Thats because I have some code in my delegated factories. This code wraps my components into proxies in order to be able to intercept method calls to These components during runtime.

Comment: Ok but where can I put the code that is inside my delegated factories? The code should not go into the components itself.

Comment: What if Component needed to implement IComponent so it wasn't registered `AsSelf()` but like `builder.RegisterType<Component>().As<IComponent>();`? You can't declare delegates in interfaces so I'm not sure how to declare the Factory method in the IComponent interface?

Answer (score 0):

In your example Lifetime Scope works well.

In your code you register a factory for delegate. It means that it will dispose an object of `Func<int, Component>`, but not for your `Component` (because it created by `Func`, not by `Autofac`).

Here is an example (Dispose is called):

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register<Component>(c=>new Component(123));

    IContainer root = builder.Build();

    using (ILifetimeScope lf = root.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var comp = lf.Resolve<Component>();     
    }
}

class Component : IDisposable
{
    public Component(int i) { }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In this example it creates an instance of `Component`and then (once `LifetimeScope`is ended) calls `Dispose`on it.

Edit:

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register<Component>(c => new Component(123));
    builder.RegisterType<ComponentUser>().AsSelf();

    IContainer root = builder.Build();

    using (ILifetimeScope lf = root.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var comp = lf.Resolve<ComponentUser>();
    }
}

class ComponentUser
{
    Component Component { get; set;}

    public ComponentUser(Func<Component> func) 
    {
        Component = func();
    }
}

class Component : IDisposable
{
    public Component(int i) { }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That how it works.

Comment: Right but as I wrote: "In http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/ it is explained that the created components by a delegate factory are put into the same lifetime scope as the delegate factory."

Comment: Furthermore I'm looking for a solution with delegate factories.

Comment: It creates components and put into the same lifetime scope as the delegate factory, if it also automatically creates factory.

Comment: Unfortunatley this doesnt help because the Client component needs to use a parameterized  delegate factory as in my example.